# PhoneGap app crashes on WP8.1

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

**tl;dr** - I can't seem to get a PhoneGap app to run successfully on WP8.1. There are a number of problems in my process of diagnosing the issue.

**Setting:** I created a PhoneGap 3.4 Windows Phone app, tested it on Windows Phone 8 using Visual Studio 2012 for WP, and submitted it. I got loads of crash reports from people with Windows Phone 8.1.

**Diagnosing the problem:** I went ahead and tried to run the app on a WP8.1 emulator using Visual Studio 2013 for Windows. I get the following error:

```
Deployment of application to device failed.
Exception from HRESULT: 0x89721500
```

I then try selecting "Retarget to Windows Phone 8.1". The app launches and the splash screen shows, but it then crashes as well and I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.SystemException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020006.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

**Tried to sideload an existing XAP:** Thinking there may just be something off in running this app via VS2013, I thought I might try sideloading it. Problem is, there isn't a XapDeploy.exe for the 8.1 emulator and I can't seem to download/open apps from the internet in the emulator.

**Trying to figure out what's what:** None of this is terribly useful, especially given how new WP8.1 is and how relatively few people deal with PhoneGap; there aren't many people who have encountered this kind of an issue so there isn't much online. I've tried everything above with a fresh app created by PhoneGap, no difference.

Any help here, pointing me in any direction, would be incredibly helpful.

**A workaround:** A workaround, if I can't get this to work, is to just exclude support for 8.1; keep people with 8.1 from downloading the app/app version. Is there any way for me to do that? I can't seem to find a way for that anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with my project. If your project is asynchronously loading more than one external file (.html, .js, ...) I found a solution.

I debugged what was the root of this problem, and getting simpler cordova seed examples it seem to run, and going slowly to my project state, I saw that it crashes in the cordova file XHRHelper.cs when I load more than one file at once.

Finally, I found in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4873 the solution. There seems to be some kind of bug with cordova and Windows Phone 8.1, that when he tries to asynchronously load more than one file, it crashes.

There's a comment there from **Maris Seimanovs** that fixed it by providing a modified XHRHelper file that has solved the issue for me: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5bf4d9ba9cdb5d0f3f3e

Remember that you can find the XHRHelper file in platforms/wp8/cordovalib/XHRHelper.cs

I hope it also helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! My apologies for the delay in getting back to you. I've gone ahead and tried replacing platforms/wp8/cordovalib/XHRHelper.cs with the Maris Seimanovs' that you linked to, and I still got the same error with the app that was retargeted to Windows Phone 8.1. Is there any other possible solution to this that you know of? I didn't see any in the bug link that you provided.

Comment: I have exactly same problem still crashing with exception indexoutofrange

Comment: Adding Maris's code allowed the app to get further, it now seems to load the app up and I can see the mainmenu but still going mental afterwards... I expect it's all new issues but at least I'm no longer getting random text appearing on the body section from the jquery $.ajax call.  I was in disbelief this bug is in cordova wp8 as nearly every modern app uses ajax calls these days??

Comment: Maris Seimanovs' modified XHRHelper worked like a charm in my case

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maris Seimanovs' modified XHRHelper also works for me.

Comment: Not necesarely related with the above, but good to know:

I have noticed the `xap` won't load if you have an empty file (0 characters length) with or without `BOM` (e.g. UTF-8 Byte-Of-Mark)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and followed all other solutions I could find but it didn't work, the *Exception thrown: 'System.SystemException' in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll* message remained.

It took me hours to discover that I had a **poorly formatted Content-Security-Policy meta tag** - I had missed off the closing quote from the content attribute.

Putting in the closing quote fixed the error. It's hard to believe a **simple markup syntax error** could bring it all crashing down so badly.

I thought I'd share this on this SO thread as this seems to be the highest Google hit for the error, and no doubt others will have the same problem as me.